# How does licencing work in Azure and local

Tags: azure, licensing

Very much a newbie question.

We have a client that would like us to embed our product in a Sitecore website. They have the licence including a number of NonProd instances.

1. Can I use a non-prod licence in an Azure paas instance for staging?
2. If I setup a local instance for development does that use up one of the NonProd licences?
3. As I am not a certified developer is it possible for my client to obtain the "Packages for XP Single" to setup a local environment using SIF?

Thanks
Fran

Comment: In regards to number three: without a license file you will not be able to run Sitecore. You must get a license through a partner agreement.

Comment: @Kieranties is it possible to use our clients licence for a local environment? Or does that use up one of their non-prod instances?

Comment: You'll have to check with your client/legal team. As a Sitecore developer you should be working for a Sitecore partner who can provide you a developer license.

Answer (score 2):

Fran towards your questions:

1. You can use a NonProd Sitecore licence in Azure Paas instance.
2. Your local development environment and all development servers containg Sitecore (for tests purposes or others) that are internal - can use the NonProd license.
3. As answered by Kieranties - Sitecore cant't run without a licence file. You can use NonProd Client's one or if you have a partner licence.

I hope these will help you.